# Trying to map Vector to (Double, Double) in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

Hi I'm quite new to spark and scala. I have a problem that need output as Array[(Double, Double)] but Mlib k cluster gives the cluster centers in form Array[Vector].

I tried the following...

```
val k_means = new KMeans().setK(k).setSeed(1L)
val kmModel = k_means.fit(transformedData)
val clusterVector = kmModel.clusterCenters

val clusters = clusterVector.map({case Vector => (Double, Double)})
clusters
```

clusters should be in form Array[(Double, Double)], but the code has something wrong

Comment: I suggest you learn more about the language syntax, functions and pattern matching. Also, you would need to provide more details about how your vectors look like.

Comment: You probably want to check out the Vector API: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/org/apache/spark/mllib/linalg/Vector.html, there are several possibly useful methods for you.

Answer (score 0):

Change `clusterVector.map({case Vector => (Double, Double)})` to

```
clusterVector.map(fields => (fields(0).toDouble,fields(1).toDouble))
```

That should do the trick

Comment: Thanks a bunch for your answer! When giving a solution like this, try to always explain what was wrong to start with and how your proposal fixes the problem :)